# Excel Array formula not working out for me

Tags: excel, formula

I have a sheet (CFG) that holds all my SKUs and Keywords. I have this formula that searches a cell for a range of values and returns the ones it found.

It works great until it's looking for a value with double 0s. I dont have any double 0s in my list of keywords, so i'm not sure why it's not working. Any help?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CFG!K$2:K$1171,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(CFG!K$2:K$1171,A2)),-1,1)*(ROW(CFG!K$2:K$1171)-ROW(CFG!K$2)+1))),"")
```

Edit: I am entering this formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

[image]

Comment: Can you try this normal formula and see if it works for you? `=LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(" "&CFG!K$2:K$1171&" "," "&A2&" ",1),CFG!K$2:K$1171)`

Comment: Like a champ, thank you soooooo much! Wish i could give you a +1 or something.

Comment: Great! Upvote the comment. It will be retained.

Comment: I did notice today that the formula is case sensitive. Is there a way to change that? Also, there's no option for me to upvote. I think im still too new. Which is dumb that i cant upvote an answer to my own question. Guess i have to let others determine if i like my answer or not.

Comment: 1. Replace FIND function with SEARCH function to deal with case sensitivity. 2. If you hover mouse on the left side of comment (which you think is useful) then a small triangle will appear which you need to press.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Also, im hovering over and it doesnt show up. The Delete button shows up on my comments when i hover over the left side of my responses, but nothing for yours.

Comment: See this discussion https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-do-i-upvote-or-downvote-comments . If you check now, I have upvoted your question comment for case sensitivity part.